# How to find the location of a gene, starting with the gene name and the DNA sequence of nucleotides?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics

I'm not a professional biologist, I'm just trying to analyze some actual data. Where should I look up the location of a gene and nucleotides it consist of? How can I find it in DNA? Is there an algorithm that can be used?

Comment: This is not clear. You have a gene and its sequence? You have a gene name and a genome sequence that could or could not have this gene? What type of "gene name" do you have? There are different identifiers for genes. If it is a standardised one, yes, you can get the gene sequence for example from Genbank and you can align the gene to a genome. But please try to make the question more specific and add more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the genomic location of a gene when you **start with a gene name**;

Use the [UCSC Genome browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgGateway). This has a number of advantages. There are a number of species to choose from. It provides a representative image of the gene and regulatory elements that surround it. It can display a **lot** of extra information if you want to see it. The disadvantage ot the UCSC Genome browser is that the information density may overload non-professional users.

To find the genomic location of a gene when you **start with a DNA sequence**;

Use the [search tool that links to the UCSC browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgBlat?hgsid=571716323_xSVZeDgwwb7MaRaGl74CiVLSjsWY&command=start).

The alternative option is to search for your [gene ID](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene) or [sequence](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch) in NCBI Gene.

To search for a DNA nucleotide sequence using the link above, select *Reference genomic sequences (refseq_genomic)* from the pull-down tab in the **Database** field. Limiting the search to a species using the **Organism** field is also wise.

Both of these sites provide the information you are after. Taking time to read the *help* instructions will be useful.